# How to find out if a string part is included in a JSON response?

Tags: python, json

Let's say the print of a JSON response `print(response)` is:

```
{'incidents': [{'text': 'FT', 'homeScore': 2, 'awayScore': 0, 'isLive': False, 'time': 90, 'addedTime': 999, 'incidentType': 'period'}, {'player': {'name': 'Jackson Porozo', 'firstName': '', 'lastName': '', 'slug': 'jackson-porozo', 'shortName': 'J. Porozo', 'position': 'D', 'userCount': 321, 'id': 978518}, 'playerName': 'Jackson Porozo', 'reason': 'Foul', 'id': 120118989, 'time': 90, 'addedTime': 4, 'isHome': False, 'incidentClass': 'yellow', 'incidentType': 'card'}
```

I'm wanting to find out if in this response we have included `'incidentType': 'card'`.

For that I tried to use:

```
if "'incidentType': 'card'" in response:
    print('Ok')
```

And I also tried using:

```
if "\'incidentType\': \'card\'" in response:
    print('Ok')
```

both did not return `Ok`, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not looking at a *JSON string*, you're looking at an already parsed Python list of dicts. So your question is how to find if any dict in the list has a key `incidentType` with value `card`:

```
if any(i['incidentType'] == 'card' for i in response['incidents']):
    ...
```

If it's not guaranteed that all dicts in the list have a key `incidentType`, use `i.get('incidentType')` instead…

Comment: Thanks for the support @deceze , it solved the problem perfectly, I'm waiting for the 7 minutes that Stack asked for so I can mark your answer as a solution, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a python dict. Use basic dict API in order to implement your logic

```
data = {'incidents': [{'text': 'FT', 'homeScore': 2, 'awayScore': 0, 'isLive': False, 'time': 90, 'addedTime': 999, 'incidentType': 'period'}, {'player': {'name': 'Jackson Porozo', 'firstName': '', 'lastName': '', 'slug': 'jackson-porozo', 'shortName': 'J. Porozo', 'position': 'D', 'userCount': 321, 'id': 978518}, 'playerName': 'Jackson Porozo', 'reason': 'Foul', 'id': 120118989, 'time': 90, 'addedTime': 4, 'isHome': False, 'incidentClass': 'yellow', 'incidentType': 'card'}]}

for entry in data['incidents']:
  if entry.get('incidentType') == 'card':
    print('Found')
```